# should I initialize collections in the constructor

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have a `many-to-many` relationship between `Foo` and `Bar`

Here's a simplified Foo

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars {get;set;}
}
```

and I want to save a new foo with some bars attached:

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.Bars.Add(bar1); //I'll get an error that if Bars is not initialized
repo.Insert(foo);
repo.SaveChanges();
```

should I initialize the Bars in the constructor, is this how it should be done ? 
(using EF4 CTP5 codefirst)

Comment: For those still interested: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9912675/908336

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd indeed initialize the collection in the constructor (if the collection is virtually always needed), or would change the getter to initialize whenever the collection is first needed (if the collection is not always needed).

Comment: well, when I don't do inserts, the EF fills it with Bars, without my initialization

Comment: May be smart to do lazy initialization then (in the getter, if Bars is not initialized, create a new collection).