# Why EF navigation property return null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two model
1)

```
public class Indicator
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int MaxPoint { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateChanged { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<CalculationType> CalculationTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<TestEntity> TestEntitys { get; set; }
    public virtual IndicatorGroup IndicatorGroup { get; set; }
}
```

2)

```
public class CalculationType
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string UnitName { get; set; }
    public int Point { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateChanged { get; set; }

    public virtual Indicator Indicator { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Сalculation> Calculations { get; set; }
}
```

I executing this code

```
var indicator = DataContext.Indicators.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID == indicatorID);
var test = DataContext.CalculationTypes.FirstOrDefault();
```

first line return null on navigation property CalculationTypes
[image]

Second line return empty collection.[image] Why?

**UPDATE**
snapshot database
[image][image]
project link https://github.com/wkololo4ever/Stankin

added Calculation

```
    public class Сalculation
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    public virtual CalculationType CalculationType { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Creator { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you disabled Lazy Loading?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev LazyLoading enabled

Comment: I guess posting your mappings would help

Comment: @jbl i loaded project on https://github.com/wkololo4ever/Stankin

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/q/4069563/1236044

Comment: @kriper have you solved the problem? I am facing the same problem with no luck.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin yes. In my case i have attached null object before  in code:)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) Is Lazy Loading enabled? If not, you need to explicitly load your navigation properties with the '.Include' syntax.

2) Are you sure EF should be able to detect that relation? Did you use Code First or Database First?

Edit: 3) Are you sure there is data in your database and that the foreign key from Indicator to IndicatorGroup has a value for that specific record? I am saying this because the value "null" is valid if there is simply no data.

P.S. If you do not see a foreign key on Indicator called "IndicatorGroupId", there might be an "IndicatorId" on the table "IndicatorGroup", in which case - going from the names you provided - your database is misconfigured and you will need to use fluent syntax or data attributes to instruct EF on how to make the foreign keys.

Comment: 3) I add snapshot databse data in my post.

Comment: In my context class I don't have `context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled` and `context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled` properties. Does that mean they are enabled by default?

Answer (score 7):

Same behavior, but different root cause than selected answer:

Navigation property can also be null if you turned off  `myContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled`

Very obvious, but this got me when I was implementing some performance improvments.

Comment: It at least solved some of my issues.Guessing, the behavior may also occur in some multithreading scenarios.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;    
DbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

If DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled is set to false, DbContext will not load child objects for some parent object unless Include method is called on parent object. Setting DbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled to true or false will have no impact on its behaviours.

If DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled is set to true, child objects will be loaded automatically, and DbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled value will control when child objects are loaded.

I think this is problem:

> Edit: 3) Are you sure there is data in your database and that the
>   foreign key from Indicator to IndicatorGroup has a value for that
>   specific record? I am saying this because the value "null" is valid if
>   there is simply no data.
>
> P.S. If you do not see a foreign key on Indicator called
>   "IndicatorGroupId", there might be an "IndicatorId" on the table
>   "IndicatorGroup", in which case - going from the names you provided -
>   your database is misconfigured and you will need to use fluent syntax
>   or data attributes to instruct EF on how to make the foreign keys.

Try to this and make sure foreign key is corrected.

```
public class CalculationType
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string UnitName { get; set; }
    public int Point { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateChanged { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IndicatorID")]
    public string IndicatorId { get; set; } //this is the foreign key, i saw in your database is: Indicator_ID, avoid this, rename it to IndicatorID or IndicatorId

    public virtual Indicator Indicator { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Сalculation> Calculations { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: All of this property enabled.

Comment: I saw the second pictures, it return empty list, did you have data for that?

Comment: I did not have data for that. When I have the data there, then they are loaded immediately. I do not understand why not work lazy loading.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding lazy loading as the opposite of what it actually is. Lazy loading means your data is automatically loaded when you access a navigation property.

Comment: Typically, the data are not loaded, when I look at the properties through "watch window" in visual studio.

Comment: Yes, you are accessing a navigation property at that time.

Comment: But then, why CalculationTypes on first line is null?

Comment: Could you please post your CalculationTypes class?

Comment: CalculationType on my question post.

Comment: sr, i mean Calculation class, not CalculationType. Did you make sure your foreign key is corrected? Try to open database and check foreign key again.

Comment: I added Calculation in my post.

Comment: In my context class I don't have `context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled`
`context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled` properties. Does that mean they are enabled by default?

Comment: `If DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled is set to true, child objects will be loaded automatically, and DbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled value will control when child objects are loaded.`
This is simply not true. With LazyLoading off, entities will not be loaded except when you call Include().

Comment: @Cavid yes, they are enabled by default

Answer (score 4):

Check this out: [Navigation Property With Code First](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/navigation-property-with-code-first-navigation-property-in-ef/) . It mentions about why navigation property is null and the solutions of it.

> By default, navigation properties are null, they are not loaded by
>   default.  For loading navigation property, we use “include” method of
>   IQuearable and this type of loading is called Eager loading.
>
> Eager loading: It is a process by which a query for one type of entity
>   loads the related entities as a part of query and it is achieved by
>   “include” method of IQueryable.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this issue, where navigation properites were not loaded, even when the `Include` statement was present.

The problem was caused by string-comparison differences between SQL Server and EF6 using .NET. I was using a `VARCHAR(50)` field as the primary key in my `customers` table and also, as a foreign key field in my `audit_issues` table. What I did not realize was that my keys in the `customers` table had two additional white space characters on the end; these characters were not present in my `audit_issues` table.

[However, SQL Server will automatically pad whitespace for string comparisons](https://support2.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316626/inf-how-sql-server-compares-strings-with-trailing-spaces). This applies for WHERE and JOIN clauses, as well as for checks on FOREIGN KEY constraints. I.e. the database was telling me string were equivalent and the constraint passed. Therefore I **assumed** that they actually were exactly equal. But that was false. DATALENGTH of one field = 10, while the DATALENGTH of the other = 8.

EF6 would correctly compose the SQL query to pull the foreign key related fields and I would see them both in the generated Sql query and in the results. However, *EF6 would silently fail* when loading the Navigation Properties because .NET does not consider those strings equal. *Watch out for whitespace in string-type foreign key fields!*.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://www.koskila.net/ef-core-returns-null-for-a-navigation-property/) helped me.

In sum :

`Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies`

In *Startup.cs*

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
              ...
            services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(builder =>
            {
                builder.UseLazyLoadingProxies(); // <-- add this
            }, ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
```

Comment: The blog post is full of inaccuracies. But even when fully correct, I wouldn't enable lazy loading unless for a very good reason. IMO it's an anti pattern. `Include` is all they need here.

Comment: I used another variant of this that I found and put it into a ContextPartial.cs file (so EF can rebuild the base context file without losing my changes). --> public partial class MyTableContext { protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) => optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies(); }

Answer (score 0):

This is a variant of [Keytrap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67999976/4427457)'s answer.  Using **.NET 6** and **EF Core 6**, I created a *ContextPartials.cs* for any custom configurations that I don't want EF's Scaffold command to overwrite:

Required Package:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies
```

Code (*ContextPartials.cs*):

```
// NOTE:  I am not using the new file-scoped namespace on purpose
namespace DataAccess.Models.MyDatabase
{
    // NOTE:  This is a partial outside of the generated file from Scaffold-DbContext
    public partial class MyDatabaseContext
    {
        // NOTE:  This enables foreign key tables to become accessible
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            => optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
    }
}
```