# EF core navigation property return null value even after using Incude

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-core

*This is not a duplicate question as I have looked up many questions including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29272581/why-ef-navigation-property-return-null), which is the closest to what I want but didn't solve the challenge.*

I have my table models relation set up this way:

```
public class User
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction
{
    public long TransactionId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public User Patient { get; set; }
}
```

fluent api setup for the entity

```
//some other modelbuilder stuff
modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity => 
{
  entity.HasMany(e => e.Transactions).WithOne(e => e.User);
  //wanted to add another entity.HasMany(e => e.User).WithOne(e => e.Patient) but efcore didn't allow me.
});
```

This generates a Transaction table with UserUserId and PatientUserId and takes the right values on save.
But when I do a get with a user Id

```
User user = dbcontext.Set<User>().Include(t => t.Transactions).FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == userId);
```

`user.Transactions` have a list of transaction all with null `Transaction.Patient`

What exactly is going on here and how do I get past it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are nesting navigations. So, you have to use `ThenInclude` like this to add `Patient` which is a navigation property of `Transaction`.

```
User user = dbcontext.Set<User>().Include(t => t.Transactions).ThenInclude(p => p.Patient).FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == userId);
```