# Entity Framework Core null relationship

Tags: entity-framework

I have created a simple EF Core to join two tables by using relationship (HasOne). But when I run it, the query only queries the master table (`Employees`) without joining to the second table (`Contact`) and it causes the model to not bind the data.

Could someone point out what I am missing in this code shown below? Thanks

```
public class Employees
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
    public Employees Employee { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
}

internal class EmployeeMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Employees>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Employees> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.EmployeeId);
        builder.Property(p => p.EmployeeId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.HasOne(x => x.Contact).WithOne(y => y.Employee).HasForeignKey<Contact>(k => k.EmployeeId);
    }
}

public class ContactMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Contact>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Contact> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(p => p.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly);
}

private EmployeeResponse GetEmployeeResponse()
{
    var emp = _context.Employees.FirstOrDefault();

    return new EmployeeResponse
        {
            ContactNumber = emp!.Contact.ContactNumber,
            EmployeeId = emp.EmployeeId,
        };
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solutions:

**1.** Enable lazy loading:

```
DbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

**2.** Or load it manually with `.Include`:

```
_context.Employees.Include(x => x.Contact).FirstOrDefault();
```

[More information about navigation propertys in ef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29272581/why-ef-navigation-property-return-null).

Comment: many online example didn't mention need to add the LazyLoadingEnabled. So, i didn't put.

Comment: Ok, use include instead... But you yave to use it in all code that uses navigation properties