# How to Load Related Data in MVC with complex table structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, dbcontext

I have several classes which I will shorten for brevity. Below they are listed with the related properties/fields associated with this question.

```
public class AcademicYear
{
    [Key]
    public int AcademicYearId { get; set; }
}

public class Division
{
    public Division()
    {
        this.CareerFields = new HashSet<CareerField>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int    DivisionId     { get; set; }

    // Foreign Keys
    public int    AcademicYearId { get; set; }

    // Navigation Properites
    public virtual AcademicYear AcademicYear { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CareerField> CareerFields { get; set; }
}

public class CareerField
{
    public CareerField()
    {
        this.Clusters    = new HashSet<Cluster>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int    CareerFieldId   { get; set; }

    // Foreign Keys
    public int    AcademicYearId  { get; set; }
    public int    DivisionId      { get; set; }


    // Navigation Properties
    public virtual AcademicYear AcademicYear { get; set; }
    public virtual Division     Division     { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Cluster>    Clusters    { get; set; }
}

public class Cluster
{
    public Cluster()
    {
        this.CareerFields = new HashSet<CareerField>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ClusterId { get; set; }
    {
        // Foreign Keys
        public int    AcademicYearId { get; set; }

        // Navigation Properties
        public virtual AcademicYear AcademicYear { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CareerField> CareerFields { get; set; }
    }
}

public class Pathway
{
    public Pathway()
    {
        this.CareerMajors = new HashSet<CareerMajor>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int    PathwayId      { get; set; }

    // Foreign Keys
    public int    AcademicYearId { get; set; }
    public int    ClusterId      { get; set; }

    // Navigation Properties
    public virtual AcademicYear AcademicYear { get; set; }
    public virtual Cluster      Cluster      { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CareerMajor> CareerMajors { get; set; }
}

public class CareerMajor
{
    public CareerMajor()
    {
        this.Courses        = new HashSet<Course>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int    CareerMajorId     { get; set; }
    public string FirstYearOffered  { get; set; }

    // Foreign Keys
    public int    AcademicYearId    { get; set; }
    public int    PathwayId         { get; set; }

    // Navigation Properties

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public virtual AcademicYear      AcademicYear      { get; set; }
    public virtual Pathway           Pathway           { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Course>         Courses        { get; set; }

}

public class Course
{
    public Course()
    {
        this.CareerMajors  = new HashSet<CareerMajor>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int    CourseId       { get; set; }

    // Foreign Keys
    public int    AcademicYearId { get; set; }
    public int?   InstructorId   { get; set; }

    // Navigation Properties
    public virtual ICollection<CareerMajor>  CareerMajors  { get; set; }

    public virtual AcademicYear AcademicYear { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a ViewModel class to load all this for my controller

```
public class CMSIndex
{
    public IEnumerable<Division> Divisions { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CareerField> CareerFields { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Cluster> Clusters { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Pathway> Pathways { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CareerMajor> CareerMajors { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

I have a razor cshtml page (the auto CRUD defined Index page) where I start with the Division and I can load the related CareerFields. However, when I try to load Clusters, I get the error message

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: source 
>    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: source

Here is my index method from the controller (note the commented out lines are what I have tried as well)

```
public ViewResult Index(Int32? divisionID, Int32? careerFieldID, Int32? clusterID, Int32? pathwayID, Int32? careerMajorID, Int32? courseID)
    {
        var viewModel = new CMSIndex();

        viewModel.Divisions = db.Divisions
            .Include(d => d.AcademicYear)
            .Include(d => d.CareerFields)//
            .Include(d => d.CareerFields.Select(cf => cf.Clusters))
            //.Select(c => c.Clusters.Select(cl => cl.Pathways.Select(p => p.CareerMajors.Select(cm => cm.Courses)))))
            .OrderBy(d => d.DivisionName);

        if (divisionID != null)
        {
            ViewBag.DivisionID = divisionID.Value;
            viewModel.CareerFields = viewModel.Divisions.Where(d => d.DivisionId == divisionID.Value).Single().CareerFields;
        }

        if (careerFieldID != null)
        {
            ViewBag.careerFieldID = careerFieldID.Value;
            //viewModel.Clusters = viewModel.CareerFields.Where(cf => cf.CareerFieldId == careerFieldID.Value).Single().Clusters;
            //viewModel.Clusters = viewModel.CareerFields.SelectMany(cf => cf.Clusters);
            viewModel.Clusters = viewModel.CareerFields.Where(cf => cf.CareerFieldId == careerFieldID.Value).Single().Clusters;
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

I am following the Contoso tutorial on loading related data. I seem to be able to load 1:m relationships, but I am unsure how to do this with m:m (e.g. CareerFields and Clusters).

And, I do have an initializer that has loaded data to pull and I am passing an ID (e.g. careerFieldID).

Where the exception is being thrown is on the line:

```
viewModel.Clusters = viewModel.CareerFields.Where(cf => cf.CareerFieldId == careerFieldID.Value).Single().Clusters;
```

And each commented variation.

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not saying that this is the issue, but have you checked the values are not null? In the line

```
viewModel.Clusters = viewModel.CareerFields
    .Where(cf => cf.CareerFieldId == careerFieldID.Value).Single().Clusters;
```

is it possible that `viewModel.CareerFields` is null?

As some side notes:

- With your null checks when you have nullables it's better to use their HasValue method e.g.

  ```
  if (divisionID.HasValue)
  {
      ...
  }
  ```
- The use of `Single()` can be a bit temperamental and can throw exceptions if no elements exist or if more than one exist. `First()` can be used to handle more than one (but this throws if none match), `SingleOrDefault()` will handle zero or one result and `FirstOrDefault()` will handle most things.
- You can save a expression by putting your lambda in the single e.g.

  ```
  viewModel.CareerFields = viewModel.Divisions
      .Single(d => d.DivisionId == divisionID.Value).CareerFields;
  ```

**Edit:** I think the issue you are having is the same as in [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858922/code-first-adding-to-collections-how-to-use-code-first-with-repositories) could you try changing your classes collections so the are initialised in the get when null. E.g for Division

```
public class Division
{
    [Key]
    public int    DivisionId     { get; set; }

    // Foreign Keys
    public int    AcademicYearId { get; set; }

    // Navigation Properites
    public virtual AcademicYear AcademicYear { get; set; }

    private ICollection<CareerField> careerFields;
    public virtual ICollection<CareerField> CareerFields { 
        get { return careerFields ?? (careerFields = new HashSet<CareerField>()); }
        set { careerFields = value; } 
    }
}
```

That's actually my preferred method anyway, this imposes it's own problem with your code as the fact that CareerFields was null means that for the given division, there are no associated CareerFields. This means that when your Single() call is hit it will throw the exception `The source contains no elements` as CareerFields will contain a empty hashset. This could be fixed by a change to SingleOrDefault().

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I am pretty sure that it is null (Clusters, not careerField.ID...I verified that was not null). I know there are values for what I am looking for in my DB, I am just unsure if I am setting my query up correctly to query for m:m relationships. Is viewModel.Clusters = viewModel.CareerFields
    .Where(cf => cf.CareerFieldId == careerFieldID.Value).Single().Clusters; correct? Also,  am I loading the related data correctly?

Comment: @Erik Your loading looks fine to me. It is not the Clusters that I believe is null but the division's career field. I edited my question but then noticed that you said 'I know there are values for what I am looking for in my DB' Entity framework does not seem to know about the CareerFields associated with the Searched Division. Are they definitely in the database, is there defiantly a many to many association between them (in a link table? is entity framework aware of it?).

Comment: The divisions are loading. It's when I select a career field to load the clusters is when it fails. The exception is thrown at the line viewModel.Clusters = viewModel.CareerFields.Where(cf => cf.CareerFieldId == careerFieldID.Value).Single().Clusters; - I have tried SingleOrDefault, but still get the null error. I can tell where the issues is. The ViewModel's CareerField.Clusters is not being loaded.I just do not know how to load them. Do I need to load it in the view model, or in the controller?

Comment: I noticed that I cannot access properties directly in my view model (e.g. I cannot access viewModel.CareerFields.Clusters). Is this because it is defined as an IEnumerable? Could this be the cause of not loading related data?

Comment: you were right. Divisions are not being loaded when I select a cluster. The divisionID is being reset and is null when attempting to select a cluster which is causing the error because viewModel.CareerFields is null. I am finding the difference between what I am doing and the Contoso example is the query strings differ. In contoso it is localhost/controller/action/id, but my url is coming up as localhost/controller/action?divisionid=1. I have the default route (and no other routes set) as controller/action/id, but it is not working correctly.

Comment: I figured it out. The issue was nothing to do with the query, but routing. I needed to created custom routes to handle the additional optional parameters. I tried {tags}/{*tags} for the catch all, but it did not fit what I was doing, so I simply made custom routes for each additional tag down to courses. I appreciate the assistance you offered. It really helped me think out the problem. +1 for the help.

Comment: @Erik, sorry wasn't on yesterday, glad to hear you solved the problem thought :D